# DataGrid View Cell Change Colour

Tags: c#, for-loop, datagridview

I am looking to change the cell color based on a condition

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (grid1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.Equals("1"))
    {

        grid1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; 
    }
}
```

Im not to sure on what is needed to change the cell color, please advise..

Comment: I tried your code: if cell content is "1" it changes text color to red for cells in the second column (i=1) of the first 5 rows. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes i am, but the fore color is not changing at all it is just staying the same, is there a property i must enable or something?

Comment: I tried it myself and it actually changes text color. Have you tried to put a breakpoint on the instruction   `grid1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;` to check if it is executed?

Comment: Instead of `.Style` try using `.DefaultCellStyle` property

Comment: I had tried this also, is there any other ways, or any of the properties of the grid i need to change..